# javascript: Lodash reject query

Tags: javascript

The following code was intended to search and remove an element from an array but is not working.

```
console.log(_.reject(['x','b','a1','ggg'],function(k){k==='x'}))
```

Was expecting

```
[ 'b', 'a1', 'ggg' ]
```

But received,

```
[ 'x', 'b', 'a1', 'ggg' ]
```

instead.

The x never got removed, any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a return statement in your `predicate`

Instead of

`_.reject(['x','b','a1','ggg'],function(k){k==='x'})`

try

`_.reject(['x','b','a1','ggg'],function(k){ return k==='x'})`

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the `return`. Check out the [documentation for reject](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#reject)

```
_.reject(['x','b','a1','ggg'], function(k) {
   return k === 'x';
});
```

In ES6, you can use arrow syntax to avoid having to explicitly include `return`, but with regular function syntax you must return a value.

```
// ES6
_.reject(['x','b','a1','ggg'], (k) => k === 'x');

// ES5
_.reject(['x','b','a1','ggg'], function(k) {
   return k === 'x';
});
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer since you gave arrow syntax demonstration